# Fasta file conversion

Tags: arrays

how can i convert a fasta file (containing peptide sequences) into a file that contain one entry per line? i would like to index it for a job array. i have 38 different fasta files to be blast with another 38 databases. For example : DB40,DB41, DB42................DB78. I want to convert those DB into data.1 .....and so forth.

im referring to this website:
http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/bioinfsupport/help/cluster_usage/submitting_array_jobs

Any help?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question: what have you tried, what problems you run into, code samples.

Comment: hi, sorry my bad for not telling it clearly. i have 38 fasta files that need to be indexed as inputs for my BLAST program. in the website that i referred to, it said "If your input data is in a file named datafile containing one entry per line, then you can use the unix sed command in your job script to pull out the line of 'datafile'  specified by $SGE_TASK_ID"  . Point is, i do not understand how to convert all my fasta files into a file that contain one entry per line. In other words, i how to convert (for example Ens40.fa into data.1)

Comment: Please use those details to improve the question, as long comments are harder to read